# how to get udp unicast to two hosts?

Tags: networking, routing, iptables, udp

The two hosts need to have to same ip.

My solution at the moment is a port mirror, but the problem is as mentioned the duplicate of the ip address, I think. I couldn't find a way to disable the IP-Address information on the Port Mirror.

Basically I get the data on the Port Mirror, however it doesn't increase my count on Packets received when typing "netstat -su". It does however work when i dont have a second device with the same IP-Address connected?

With duplicate IP-s I still get the packets on my device according to wireshark, but I don't get it in my application as netstat implies.

Or what other ways are there to achieve this?
I've seen iptables TEE, but couldn't get it to work.
Thanks in advance

Edit: I think the problem is that the MAC-Address changes when i connect the second device. So that my application doesn't receive the packets because the MAC Address isnt the same i guess?

Any way to change the MAC-Address of incoming packages?

Comment: Why are you trying to solve a multicast scenario with unicast in the first place?

Comment: The camera does not have multicast support and cannot be altered. I managed to change the mac-address so that I have a duplicate IP/MAC-address system, but it's on a port mirror which is configured in such a way that it is not seen from other devices, I think (need to verify still). However I don't really like changing the MAC-Address, I also tried promisc mode on the interface, but still could not get the packets.